# Python DLL registration problems

Tags: python, dll, com

I have a piece of hardware which I am trying to control over USB. The vendor provides a set of DLL files which can be used for this purpose.

I have found [Win32com , how select coclass interface?](http://osdir.com/ml/python-windows/2006-10/msg00069.html), that someone else has done what I want to do. Here they are using `win32com.client.Dispatch("BK.BasicEnv.Application.RemoteAPI")` in order to create the RemoteAPI object. However when I try this, I get the error `'Class not registered'`.

If I try to register the DLL which contains RemoteAPI using `regsvr32` I get the error `"The module "BasicEnvRemoteAPI.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found"`. If I try with `/i /n`, I get that `DllInstall` was not found.

So I cannot create the object I want because the DLL is not registered... but I cannot register the DLL?

How do I register the DLL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system is telling you that this DLL does not implement a COM server. If it did, then it would export a function named `DllRegisterServer` that would perform self-registration.  You'll need to go back to the documentation for this hardware, or whoever supplied you with the accompanying software, to work out how you are meant to register the COM server.

All the evidence points to your DLL not implementing a COM server.

**Update**

Your comments suggest that this is in fact a managed DLL. In which case you should register it with regasm.

Comment: The C# user guide says: The BZ5503 (software that the DLLs come with) installation directory is not used by the example program, but its contents must be copied into a directory called ‘ExecuteLibrary’ in the ‘RemoteApi-2250SDK’ solution; see page 3.

So it seems like the DLLs should be copied to a place where the C# program can find them. As for Python...?

Comment: That doesn't much sound like a COM server to me.

Comment: The documentation gives:
"Class giving programatic access to remote control of instruments of Type 2250, or equivalent types. The class implements a number of interfaces, each useful for a particular aspect of the remote controlling process. All interfaces can be used from COM as dual interfaces. 

Namespace: BK.BasicEnv.Application
Assembly: BasicEnvRemoteAPI (in BasicEnvRemoteAPI.dll) Version: 1.0.0.0 (4.3.1.81)"

In the C# code, they use it by:
using BK.BasicEnv.Application;
...
api = new RemoteAPI();

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer. Sounds like it's a managed assembly. Use `regasm` to register it.